# htaccess strip query string from using redirectmatch

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to apply a redirect rule using redirectmatch 301 like below

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/product-category/babies-tots/ https://mothersenvogue.com.hk/shop/all-babies-tots?`

It does work. However, the appended query string like the example below does not get stripped.

http://mev-hongkong.com/product-category/babies-tots/?add_to_wishlist=8836

How can I strip the ?add_to_wishlist=8836 parameter to just redirect it to https://mothersenvogue.com.hk/shop/all-babies-tots/ ?

Comment: Don’t think that is possible using RedirectMatch, you might have to use a RewriteRule for that.

Comment: @CBroe can you assist on writing the RewriteRule for that? I'm not too experienced with mod_rewrite so any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `RewriteRule ^product-category/babies-tots/$ https://mothersenvogue.com.hk/shop/all-babies-tots? [L,R=301]` should basically do the job.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work jumping off from one domain to another.